# what does this mean Superfluous name server listed at parent: ns52.domaincontrol.com?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I get this message from pingdom

Superfluous name server listed at parent: ns52.domaincontrol.com

A name server listed at the parent, but not at the child, was found. This is most likely an administrative error. You should update the parent to match the name servers at the child as soon as possible.

http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=holidayniseko.com&timestamp=1417682368

I have read about this but one thing that is different in our case is we also get

Too few name servers (1).

Only one name server was found for the zone. You should always have at least two name servers for a zone to be able to handle transient connectivity problems.

AND

we are not using private name servers, just Go Daddy name servers.

how can this be resolved?

### Post note

I would like to add that other stuff I had read had been related to private name servers and hence not related to this as we are using Go Daddy name servers. (I'll try and find the information to make my question better) Our records were set up over 6 years ago and the problem only appeared 2 -3 weeks ago, reports of people unable to access our site.

After 6 talks with Go Daddy and numerous hours in between each call over 6 days no resolution was found even though the zone file looked strange from day 1 and finally the zone file was refreshed and the problem was fixed.

Comment: It looks like you've since addressed the issue ( see http://www.intodns.com/holidayniseko.com ) but your mail will have trouble at some point.

Comment: thanks @avery , yes Go Daddy in the end fixed the problem after 7 hours on the phone. I see the MX error records unsure if hey were like that yesterday

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two error messages are both indications of the same misconfiguration. In the `com.` zone, you have two NS records pointing to `ns51.domaincontrol.com.` and `ns52.domaincontrol.com.`

Both respond to queries for the zone, however when either of those servers are queried for NS records for the zone, they only report `ns51.domaincontrol.com.`

The likely explanation is that you are simply missing one NS record in the zone itself, indicating that `ns52.domaincontrol.com.` is also NS for the zone.

One error message tells you that `ns52.domaincontrol.com.` is in glue, but not in the zone, the other tells you that the zone only has a single NS record. Adding one NS record with `ns52.domaincontrol.com.` would make both messages go away.

It also tells you "Too few IPv4 name servers", which I find ironical, because you have even fewer IPv6 name servers. It is btw. redundant because it already you only have one.

Comment: thanks, you said "The likely explanation is that you are simply missing one NS record in the zone itself" that was evident from day 1 as I have since written , what I am wondering is firstly how this disappeared? 

and then my original question on how can I resolve it has been answered in part by the fact Go Daddy were finally able to refreshed the zone file.

Comment: @simon Regarding how it disappeared I think you would have to reach out to the relevant service provider to see if they can provide any kind of audit log for changes to your zone data, alternatively if they had any problems with their service that caused the data to change by itself. This part of the question does not appear to be answerable by anyone else but the service provider as it's not a question about dns per se but about what has happened in their environment.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist thank you for your comment, it was a kind of rhetorical question as I knew that would be the answer but again thanks for the useful information and technical jargon, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It means that the parent name servers list `ns51.domaincontrol.com` and `ns52.domaincontrol.com` as the name servers for `holidayniseko.com` but that only ns51.domaincontrol.com is listed as a name server at the name servers themselves.

querying ns51.domaincontrol.com for the NS record for `holidayniseko.com` lists itself as a name server.

querying ns52.domaincontrol.com for the NS record for `holidayniseko.com` lists ns51.domaincontrol.com as a name server.

So again, ns51 and ns52 are listed as name servers at the parent name servers but only ns51 is listed as a name server at the name servers themselves.

Comment: thank you @joequerty, I would tick the answer but I can't.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: @simon you should be able to mark this answer as correct.