# DNS problems after switching to Custom nameservers

Tags: vps, nameserver, dkim, soa-record

hope you can help me with this...

Last week I was required by my registar to switch from default to custom DNS servers (`ns1.status2.com` / `ns2.status2.com`) on my domain (`status2.com`) in order to enable DKIM on my VPS Server.

After this change was made (and DKIM successfully enabled) I noticed the following errors when checking my dns health via: `dnscheck.pingdom.com`

- Superfluous name server listed at parent: `ns1.status2.com`
- Superfluous name server listed at parent: `ns2.status2.com`
- Total parent/child glue mismatch.

At this point I reported these errors to a registar support agent and they reset the DNS records but the problem persists. Also there are the following records:

- 2 different serials found.
- 2 different SOA records found.
- Delivery over IPv4 to `dnsadmin@v144.vps.unifiedlayer.com` could not be done. Failed to deliver email for SOA RNAME of `status2.com` (`dnsadmin.v144.vps.unifiedlayer.com`) using `dnsadmin@v144.vps.unifiedlayer.com`

Comment: check this question that already asked: http://serverfault.com/questions/649228/what-does-this-mean-superfluous-name-server-listed-at-parent-ns52-domaincontrol

it looks like different number of NS records are listed in parent zone and child zone itself.

Answer (score 2):

As can been seen [here](http://www.viewdns.info/dnsreport/?domain=status2.com) more clearly:

```
Missing NS records at parent servers    Oops! It appears that the following 

nameserves listed at your local servers are not listed at the parent servers:

ns1.bluehost.com. 
ns2.bluehost.com. 

You should ensure that these nameservers are valid and working. If they are not, you will encounter connectivity issues with your domain.
FAILED  Missing NS records at local servers Oops! It appears that the following nameserves listed at the parent servers are not listed at your local servers:

ns1.status2.com. 
ns2.status2.com. 

You should ensure that these nameservers are valid and working. If they aren't, it can cause odd behaviour including some people not being able to access your domain.
```

Generally this is saying that you've changed the nameservers at the parent level (to point to `ns1/ns2.status2.com`) but haven't updated the `NS` records on your local DNS. You need to update the `NS` records locally to point to `ns1/ns2.status2.com`.

Same thing for your SOA record:

```
SOA primary nameserver listed at parent Oops! The primary nameserver listed in your SOA record (ns1.bluehost.com.) is not listed at the parent servers! This could suggest a configuration issue with your SOA record.
```

You need to update the nameservers in the SOA record.

Your SOA expire value isn't within the normal range:

```
Your SOA Expire value (3600000) is outside of the recommended range of 1 week (604800) to 4 weeks (2419200).
```